# FastAPI - Websocket doesn't work after refreshing

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, fastapi

I'm trying to use FastAPI to server a websocket application.
This is the code:

```
from concurrent.futures.thread import ThreadPoolExecutor
import asyncio
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, WebSocket
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from starlette.templating import Jinja2Templates
from starlette.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect

import Rpg

app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")


@app.get("/")
def serve_home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", context={"request": request})


@app.websocket("/game")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    try:
        await websocket.accept()
        background_tasks.add_task(await Rpg.triggerStartGame(websocket))
    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        await websocket.close(1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

Everything works fine, problem is that after refreshing the page, instead of getting the page as it is, nothing seems to be happening and no error is thrown. What should I do in order to make the page available after refreshing?

PS: I can't provide you what happens in **await Rpg.triggerStartGame(websocket)** as it's a really big application, however the only thing it actually does is using **websocket.send_text()** and **websocket.receive_text()**
PS2: Before using FastAPI I did all of the above using Quart and asyncio and everything worked great and even If I would refresh a thousand times it would still work. I probably can use asyncio as well here, I'd like to avoid it though.

Thanks for your time!

**UPDATE:**
I used **log_level**="debug" and after reloading for the first time the log is showing this:

```
DEBUG:    < CLOSE 1001 (going away) [2 bytes]
DEBUG:    = connection is CLOSING
DEBUG:    > CLOSE 1001 (going away) [2 bytes]
DEBUG:    x closing TCP connection
DEBUG:    = connection is CLOSED
```

Since it's closing the connection why it cannot restore it upon reloading the webpage?

Comment: what does this await Rpg.triggerStartGame(websocket) return? Is that a callable that should be executed in a background thread?

Comment: It does not really return something, it's just supposed to start running an independent task which then handles I/O alone.

Comment: What page refresh hangs? / or /game?

Comment: Why do you out in into add_task then? With add task you would do something like  def long_running_function() ... background_tasks.add_task(long_running_function) which will lead to the long_running_function being exectued in the background. But this might be another thing then.

Comment: @kosciej16 Not sure, I think /, since nothing at all is loaded?

Comment: @SimonHawe if I don't do background_tasks.add() then upon opening a second tab from the same browser, the application starts throwing errors unstoppably.